# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Nothing has changed that I know about. Upon running the command: `docker ps` the shell reports:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Exploring further i.e. with the daemon:

[image]

I'm expecting to see either a list of running containers or an empty list. Whats happening with my Docker engine?

Comment: Your Docker engine service is not running, `systemd` is reporting that attempts to start the Docker service have failed.  What do the Docker logs say when you try to start the Docker service?

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Ubuntu 19.04

The following steps worked for me;

```
$ sudo dockerd 
unable to configure the Docker daemon with file /etc/docker/daemon.json: EOF
```

Then read somewhere that `daemon.json` shouldn't be present. So,

```
$ sudo rm /etc/docker/daemon.json
```

Finally,

```
$ sudo dockerd
```

and the docker service is up-and-running again.